# Ubuntu is not opening after removing windows from laptop

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, grub-efi, reset

Ubuntu is not opening after removing Windows from the laptop.

I cannot see grub and the only thing on the screen is: `Reset System`. Please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Did you also delete the ESP - efi system partition (FAT32). Both Window & Ubuntu have their boot files in that partition. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  If ESP is missing, you have to create a new one with gparted, or Boot-Repair/grub has no place to install into.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)